# What does Phusion Passenger mean when it's described as not needing any configuration?

Tags: ruby, passenger

I'm new to Ruby, and have Phusion Passenger installed. I got it working by  [following the instructions for Nginx](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_installing_phusion_passenger_for_nginx_through_the_installer).

Specifically, from their page, I do not understand this assertion:

> Deployment is only a matter of uploading application files. No Ruby (on Rails)-specific server configuration required!

If that is the case, why do i seem to need a config.ru file? I was thinking I'd be able to drop an index.rb file in the passenger_root and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `config.ru` is not so much configuration actually. In fact it is the main entry point to a Rack application (e.g a Rails app, but also Sinatra and others). As such it is part of your application and not part of the webserver configuration.

Comment: I come from a PHP background, so I'm a bit confused what layer the config.ru belongs to. I installed Phusion Passenger. Is Sinatra a part of it? I'm trying to figuire out where to begin educating myself from here, moving forward, now that I get a hello world page. I've checked via 'gem list sinatra', and I don't have any gem like that.

Comment: Nevermind, I discovered [this page](http://titusd.co.uk/2010/04/07/a-beginners-sinatra-tutorial/) and I think I now understand. Config.ru is used by the rack layer of the framework, it seems.

Comment: Yes, both Rails and Sinatra and about every other request/response oriented web framework in Ruby builds upon Rack to communicate with a web server.

Answer (score 0):

The reference is talking about the webserver configuration part. E.g. you need not include any reverse proxy stuff in the virtual host config of apache. Thats different from using thin etc.